# Is there much point to getting a sport pilot license if you don't intend to buy a Light Sport Aircraft?

Tags: light-sport-aircraft

It seems difficult, if not impossible to rent a Light Sport Aircraft, hence my question.  Unless you had a friend with an LSA it wouldn't be much use to hold that license, would it?

Comment: Its not impossible to rent an LSA.

Comment: Where are you trying to rent an LSA?

Comment: This is in the north Houston area.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* find light sport airplanes for rent. They may not be at every flight school or FBO, but they are out there and they are available.

I find both the sport pilot and recreational pilot certificates to be a bit useless, the latter is definitely such because there are only about 600 license recreational pilots in the United States at this time. Originally, the sport pilot certificate was created as an economical entry into general aviation, aircraft ownership and future ratings.  Sadly, this proved to be a great disappointment caused by a myopic study of the general aviation market. Most LSAs purchased today are done so buy commercial or airline transport rated pilots as a light airplane to fly around locally on the weekends and come fully equipped IFR-capable glass cockpits, digital autopilots, BRS parachutes - the works. Prices now range from 170,000 to a whopping 380,000 in the case of an Icon A5 - a far cry from the simple day VFR inception of the LSA with minimal avionics.

As for the usefulness to a light supports pilot certificate, they can be used, but require additional training and logbook endorsements in order to fly cross country or at night, etc.  personally if you really want to use a pilots license to travel around the country or to different destinations, you will want to obtain a private pilot certificate. It offers the least restrictions short of commercial flight operations.

Answer (score 0):

The training requirements and checkride are nearly the same for Sport and Private, and getting a Sport license first doesn’t help at all if you later upgrade to Private. The only difference is the latter requires you pass at least one class 3 Medical exam, and the former only requires you to have a current DL.

If you worry that you can’t pass that one medical exam but haven’t yet been denied, then yes, there’s a point to getting a Sport license: it’s your only option if you want to be a pilot.

LSA rental options are indeed currently fairly limited, but that will presumably change over time—especially if the proposed weight limit increase ever gets adopted—and your license is good for life.

Also, you can look into creating a club or partnership with other Sport pilots in your area to buy an LSA.  Any school that does Sport training should be able to help get their graduates connected for such a purpose.